# What did the author mean with his comment about the input of a user-defined type?

Tags: c++, istream

This is an example extracted from section **10.3.3 Input of User-defined Types** from the book "The C++ Programming Language" second edition, by B. Stroustrup. The code is old but still compiles with minor changes. Example:

> ```
> #include <istream>
> #include <complex>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> istream& operator>>(istream& s, complex<double>& a)
> {
>     // input formats for a complex; "f" indicates a float:
>     //
>     //   f
>     //   (f)
>     //   (f, f)
>
>     double re = 0, im = 0;
>     char c = 0;
>
>     s >> c;
>     if( c == '(' ) {
>         s >> re >> c;
>         if( c == ',' ) s >> im >> c;
>         if( c != ')' ) s.clear(ios::badbit);  // set state
>     }
>     else {
>         s.putback(c);
>         s >> re;
>     }
>
>     if( s ) a = complex<double>(re, im);
>     return s;
> }
> ```
>
> Despite the scarcity of error-handling code, this will actually handle
>   most kinds of errors. **The local variable `c` is initilized to avoid
>   having its value accidentally `'('` after a failed operation.** The
>   final check of the stream state ensures that the value of the argument
>   `a` is changed if everything went well.

I failed to understand the phrase emphasized above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `s >> c` fails then `c` is not written to.

If `c` was uninitialized , it remains uninitialized at the point of the test `if( c == '(' )`. Reading an uninitialized `char` causes undefined behaviour.

The author is talking about a possible way that this undefined behaviour might manifest itself.

---

The suggested fix of `char c = 0;` relies on the fact that`s.putback(c);` does nothing if `s` is not `good()`. This is OK, although IMHO it would be clearer to write:

```
char c;
s >> c;

if ( !s )
    return s;
```

Then anybody reading the code can immediately see that it behaves properly in case of error; instead of having to thread their way through the flow of the function and check that no other operations will do anything unexpected.

Comment: *"s.putback(c); will be executed. This would actually put back a null byte"* - not so, as if `s >> c` failed the stream's left in an error state and the `putback` sentry check fails, becoming a no-op.  (Separately, from C++11 `s >> c` sets `c` to `0` on failure, so it doesn't need to be explicitly initialised in code.)

Comment: @TonyD OK - turns out I was reading at streambuf putback, not istream putback

Comment: @M.M Why the `s.clear(ios::badbit);` in the statement
`if ( c != ')' )  s.clear(ios::badbit);`  above?

Comment: @JohnKalane you seem to have a new question, post it using the "Ask Question" button. You can include link to this post if you think it's relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens if we didn't initialize `c`:

```
char c;
s >> c;
if (c == '(') { ... }
```

We are not checking to see if `>>` succeeded or failed. So if `c == '('`, it could be for one of two reasons:

1. The `>>` succeeded and we retrieved the character `'('` from the `istream`.
2. The `>>` failed, but the random byte that happened to be in the memory for `c` when it was created is a `'('`.

If you initialize `c` to `0`, case 2 is impossible: if the operation failed, we know that `c` will be `0`... so we will know for sure that if we got a `'('` it's because it came from the `istream`.