# Why `s.clear(ios::badbit);` below? Why not `s.clear(ios::failbit);`?

Tags: c++, istream

I was looking into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30563673/3694387) and I have no problem understanding the two answers given to it. But I'm not sure I understood the `s.clear(ios::badbit);` in the statement highlighted below with the comment `// set state`. For instance, why not `s.clear(ios::failbit);` instead?

> ```
> #include <istream>
> #include <complex>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> istream& operator>>(istream& s, complex<double>& a)
> {
>     // input formats for a complex; "f" indicates a float:
>     //
>     //   f
>     //   (f)
>     //   (f, f)
>
>     double re = 0, im = 0;
>     char c = 0;
>
>     s >> c;
>     if( c == '(' ) {
>         s >> re >> c;
>         if( c == ',' ) s >> im >> c;
>         if( c != ')' ) s.clear(ios::badbit);  // set state
>     }
>     else {
>         s.putback(c);
>         s >> re;
>     }
>
>     if( s ) a = complex<double>(re, im);
>     return s;
> }
> ```

Comment: I misread your question, initially, so my original comment is Just Plain Silly. Please feel free to ignore it. :-)

Comment: I agree, it should be failbit.

Comment: The version of that operator provided by the standard library does in fact set `failbit`, not `badbit` in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book you're quoting was published in 1991, 7 years before the first ISO C++ standard was even published. It's not clear why the author chose to use `ios::badbit` because no rationale was provided in either the 2nd or 3rd editions of the book.

In C++98, a non-member overload for `operator>>` was added for `complex`. This mandates that `failbit` is required to be set in the case of bad input rather than `badbit`.

N1905 26.2/13

```
template < class T , class charT , class traits >
basic_istream < charT , traits >&
operator > >( basic_istream < charT , traits >& is , complex <T >& x );
```

> *Requires:* The input values be convertible to `T`.
>
> If bad input is encountered, calls `is.setstate(ios::failbit)` (which
>   may throw `ios::failure` (27.4.4.3).

Comment: You mean N1905 26.2.6/13 instead of N1905 26.2/13, which corresponds to [§26.5.6/13 in C++1z](http://eel.is/c++draft/complex.ops#13). Thanks (+1).

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, why not s.clear(ios::failbit); instead?

`std::ios::failbit` is intended for recoverable errors. How do you recover from an input stream that is supposed to contain a pair of numbers separated by a comma and enclosed in parentheses after you've already read up to and including the comma?

You might be able to do that, but that would entail somehow backing up (backing up to where?) using `tellg` and `seekg` -- and then what? There is no recovery, so setting the `badbit` is the right thing to do.